# Use alternative Open Branch on Remote url with Visual Studio Code Git Lens when using specific ssh endpoint

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitlens

I have repository that can only pull and push from git@ssh.example.com but the UI of the git instance is at example.com. So when I want to click Open Branch on Remote in Git Lens of Visual Studio Code it opens the ssh.example.com url.

I don't know what to try but I expect a way to alter my url for use by git lens.